# Can I create a SITE template and propagate changes to all sites in a collection using this template?

Tags: master-page, project-templates

I have seen postings and responses about using a page layout master to propagate changes across all projects sites using the template.  Not quite sure HOW this is done, but my question is this...

When I create a project site template, which includes left navigation, top navigation, and sub-site pages  can I design a template that when changes are made to the parent template, will propagate to all other sites in the collection using this template?

Also, is there a link to a 'How to' site or tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint site templates don't work that way. Think of a site template as a one-time set of instructions for creating a site. Once your site is created from the instructions, it has no association to the template that was used to creating it.  So, to make modifications to all sites in a site collection you would need a PowerShell script, feature, or app that iterates through your sites and executes the logic you need to modify the sites in the site collection.